Finding an order containing the algebraic integer $\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{7}$.
I have the following definition: A subset $\mathcal{O} \subset \mathbb{C}$ is called an order if:

$1 \in \mathcal{O}$
$u, v \in \mathcal{O}$ implies $u + v, uv, -u \in \mathcal{O}$
There exists $u_1, \ldots, u_n \in \mathcal{O}$ such that
$$\mathcal{O} = \{m_1u_1 + \cdots + m_nu_n \ \mid \ m_1, \ldots, m_n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$

There are also some theorems like a complex number is an algebraic integer if and only if it is contained in an order. I want to find an order containing $\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{7}$. I know how to, for example, find a polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ with $\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{7}$ as a root: $x^4 - 20x^2 + 16$, so clearly it is an algebraic integer and therefore contained in an order, but does this help me at all in actually finding an order that contains $\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{7}$? I'm really unsure how to even start, or what it means to find an order at all in the first place, and trying to find resources on this gives me things that are far too advanced for the course I'm taking. I can't even tell if 'order' as its used in these more advanced algebra resources are even the same as this order at all. Does anyone have any ideas to help me get on the right track? Thanks for your time.

since your $\alpha=\sqrt3+\sqrt7$ is an algebraic integer (as you already proved), $\mathcal O=\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ will work, with $u_k = \alpha^{k-1}$, $k\leq 4$

@user8268 Okay, trying to wrap my head around what this definition is even saying. Is $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ the set of linear combinations(?) of $\alpha$ with integer coefficients, like: ${a + b(\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{7}) \ \mid \ a, b \in \mathbb{Z}}$? What even are these $u_k$s representing? Why is there power terms of $\alpha$ involved at all if that is what $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ is?

@debord The set $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is the set of polynomials in $x$ with integer coefficients, and $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ is the set you get by evaluating such polynomials at $x=\alpha$.  This is needed because orders are closed under multiplication, so if you have $\alpha$, you also need $\alpha^2$, $\alpha^3$, $\alpha^4$, $\alpha^5$, etc.  Do you see why it's enough to stop at $\alpha^3$?

$\Bbb{Z}[\alpha]$ denotes the smallest ring (inside some ambient field, here $\Bbb{R}$ suffices, but often we want $\Bbb{C}$) that contains $\Bbb{Z}$ as well as $\alpha$. In particular, it is closed under multiplication. This forces the powers $(\sqrt3+\sqrt7)^k$ in there.
